# didSelect does not work in UICollectionviewCell to select UICollectionViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I wrote `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` func in `UICollectionViewCell` to select a `UICollectionViewController`. I wrote the code in two ways but it doesnot work at all. Also, I don't getting an error in there.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if indexPath.item == 0 {

        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let controller1 = DigitalSLRCon(collectionViewLayout: layout)
        let nav = UINavigationController()
        nav.pushViewController(controller1, animated: true)
```

// OR

```
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let controller1 = DigitalSLRCon(collectionViewLayout: layout)
        navigationController?.pushViewController(controller1, animated: true)

    }
```

Comment: i added UICollectionViewDelegate and UICollectionViewDatasource with UICollectionviewCell as protocal

Answer (score 1):

`didSelectItemAtIndexpath`is a function of `UICollectionViewDelegate` - you don't implement it in the cell, but in your CollectionView's delegate, so probably the view controller which contains the collection view.

1. Make the UIViewController that holds the collection view conform to `UICollectionViewDelegate` protocol
2. Assign that view controller to collection view's `delegate` property
3. Implement the `didSelectItemAtIndexpath` function in the view controller

Comment: can you tell me please another way

Comment: can tell me please another way. it is very hard to cell.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the delegates from the `UICollectionViewCell` The delegates are not for the cell but the UICollectionView handler

If you want to change some element in the cell

you can override the default variables in the cell like this

```
override var isSelected: Bool {
   didSet {
      if isSelected {
         //do something
      } else {
         //not selected
      }
   }
}

override var isHighlighted: Bool {
   didSet {
      if isHighlighted {
         //do something
      } else {
         //not selected
      }
   }
}
```